# A "wireless engineering" community in the Stack exchange?

Tags: feature-request

As a engineer working on the wireless domain, I would like to propose to start a "wireless engineering" community in the Stack exchange.

The community will discuss topic as below

Cellular (includes LTE, WCDMA...etc)
Short range wireless (802.11abgn/ac, Bluetooth, Zigbee, NFC...etc)
Microwave, RF, antenna design and EM theory
Subsystem of wireless technology such as IMS, wireless security, OSS..etc.
Hetnet, small cell, wlan-offloading

Comment: Been tried at least 3 times and it never makes it out of Area 51.

Answer (score 2):

It'll probably be on-topic in the <s>proposed</s> [Engineering](http://engineering.stackexchange.com). <s>Let's wait a bit?</s> - it is in beta already (anyway, that's not a right place for your proposal; sites are proposed in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).)